# How can i prevent the attachment content from displaying in the body of the message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, vcalendar

I'm working on an asp.net c# application that sends an email with one attachment.
The attachment is a vCalendar file.
Here's the code:

```
            StringBuilder sbCalendar = new StringBuilder();
            DateTime dtStart = eventDate;
            DateTime dtEnd = eventDate;

            sbCalendar.AppendLine("METHOD: REQUEST");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("PRODID:-//DP//NET");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("MIMEDIR//ENVERSION:1.0");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + dtStart.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"));
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + dtStart.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"));
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("DTEND:" + dtEnd.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"));
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + eventLocation);
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + eventBody);
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("SUMMARY:" + eventSubject);
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("PRIORITY:3");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("UID:" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION:MAILTO:required@participant.foo");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("ATTENDEE;ROLE=CHAIR;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:MAILTO:chair@foo.foo");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("CLASS:PUBLIC");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:organizer@foo.foo");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:0");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("STATUS:TENTATIVE");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
            sbCalendar.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbCalendar.ToString());

            Stream contentStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("localhost");

            MailMessage memo = new MailMessage();

            memo.IsBodyHtml = true;

            memo.From = new MailAddress("from@ddress.foo");

            foreach (string emailAddress in emailAddresses)
            {
                memo.To.Add(emailAddress);
            }

            memo.Body = messageBody;
            memo.Subject = messageSubject;

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(contentStream, "termenLitigiu.ics", "text/calendar");
            attachment.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
            memo.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            smtp.Send(memo);
```

This works and does what is supposed to do, it sends a working (recognized by outlook) vcalendar file.

The problem is that in the body of the mail, besides the contents of the messageBody parameter, the contents of the attached file also appear, something like this:

From: sender
Sent: Tuesday, October 05, 2010 4:59 PM
To: someemail

> messageBody contents here
>
> METHOD: REQUEST
>   BEGIN:VCALENDAR
>   PRODID:-//DP//NET
>   MIMEDIR//ENVERSION:1.0
>   METHOD:REQUEST
>   BEGIN:VEVENT
>   DTSTAMP:20101006T135934Z
>   DTSTART:20101006T135934Z
>   DTEND:20101006T135934Z
>   LOCATION:Minstead
>   DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:My first meeting
>   SUMMARY:Learning Calendaring and Scheduling
>   PRIORITY:3
>   UID:721d9e3c-9010-47f5-9ad0-83c38cb0cbb7
>   ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION:MAILTO:someemail
>   ATTENDEE;ROLE=CHAIR;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:MAILTO:someemail
>   CLASS:PUBLIC
>   ORGANIZER:MAILTO:someemail
>   SEQUENCE:0
>   STATUS:TENTATIVE
>   END:VEVENT
>   END:VCALENDAR

I want to get rid of that text, and display only the contents of my messageBody parameter and have the vCalendar file just attached to the mail message.
How can i do this? Is this an outlook issue or a coding issue?

Edit: I'm only interested in displaying the message in Microsoft Outlook. I've looked into the source of the message (in Outlook right click > View Source) and the text i want to get rid of is within the `<body`>`</body`> html tags of the message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.dispositiontypenames.attachment.aspx

In the constructor of the Attachment I replaced `"text/calendar"` with `MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet` and set the `DispositionType` to `Attachment` as opposed to `Inline` which was probably the default value.

```
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(contentStream, "termenLitigiu.ics", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
            attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
```

It now gives me a clean mail message with the body of the message containing what it should and a working .ics attachment.