# Sending RTF attachment with C# fails on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, rtf, smtpclient

I'm using the .NET smtpclient to send an email with an RTF attachment. I've used this code a bazillion times before, but never to send an attached RTF to an iOS client. Using the first-gen iPad and iPhone 4S, when I attempt to view the message, the RTF code is embedded as text in the message instead of arriving as a separate attachment.

This works on other email clients, but is picky about iOS. I understand that RTF support came late to iOS, but if I create a message + RTF attachment with Outlook, the iOS email client reads it properly.

Is RTF still badly-supported? Any hints on troubleshooting or even where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: Where's your code? This could be a number of issues and posting the code would help narrow it down. I'd probably start by checking that you have the correct MIME type.

Comment: Indeed, it had to do with Mime type. The app was using "text/rtf", which apparently iOS has trouble with. Instead, I used MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet and set DispositionType to DispositionTypeNames.Attachment. It's explained in this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870562/how-can-i-prevent-the-attachment-content-from-displaying-in-the-body-of-the-mess